# Scoped storage grant access to folder and copy file from internal storage (filesDir/cacheDir)

Tags: android, android-storage, scoped-storage

How to open a folder picker and grand access to a folder(for example Download folder) using the Storage Access Framework. And then to copy file from internal storage(for example cache) to the granted folder.

Currently I able to open the document tree with editable file name.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/zip"
        putExtra(fileName)
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

Then I copy the file

```
override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?
) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        resultData?.data?.also { uri ->
            val fd: ParcelFileDescriptor =
        FacenseApp.instance.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")!!
    val fos = FileOutputStream(fd.fileDescriptor)

    try {
        fos.write(File(fromFilePath).readBytes())
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        fos.close()
        fd.close()
    }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the code create file first, but I want to grant access to the whole folder and copy/create file without editable file name input.

Comment: "I want to grant access to the whole folder" -- use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to request access to a document tree (folder) from the user.

Comment: Whether you use a stream or a file descriptor is up to you, as it is with your current code. What document trees will be available to the user will vary by OS version (and possibly by device manufacturer or device configuration).

Comment: when I am using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and `contentResolver.openOutputStream(Uri.parse(uriFromActivityResult.path + "/test-test.zip"))!!` I got `No content provider: /tree/primary%3ADocuments/test-test.zip`

Comment: That is not how you use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. Wrap the `Uri` that you get back in `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`. That gives you a `DocumentFile` that you can use to call `createNewFile()`, to give you a `DocumentFile` representing your desired document. That document's `DocumentFile` has `getUri()` to use with `openOutputStream()`.

Answer (score 0):

Show Document tree

```
 startActivityForResult(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE),
            requestCode
        )
```

`destUri` is the `Uri` from `Intent` in `onActivityResult`.

`fromFilePath` is the path from my internal storage (cache in my case).

`targetDisplayName` is the name of the file that will be created in public folder that was selected in `Document tree`

```
fun copyToPublicFolder(targetDisplayName: String, fromFilePath: String, destUri: Uri) {
    val documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(FacenseApp.instance, destUri)!!
    val createFile = documentFile.createFile(MIME_TYPE_ZIP, targetDisplayName)
    val fos = FacenseApp.instance.contentResolver.openOutputStream(createFile!!.uri)!!

    try {
        fos.write(File(fromFilePath).readBytes())
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        fos.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can do it without any issues:

```
public static void copyFile(Context context, Uri uri, File destination) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int size = is.available();
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buff)) > 0) {
            os.write(buff, 0, len);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();

        Log.d("TAG", "copyFile: " + "Copy Done...");
    }
```